# App crashed due to Firebase try to write crash report in read only database

Tags: android

Some time application has crashed because the firebase crash report try to store the value in the read only database. I don't know why their database has been read only. Please give me a solution.

Here the crash log:

```
D: Logging event (FE): app_exception(_ae), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=crash, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=SelectActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-8244797341152687840, timestamp=1526448971529, fatal=1}]
V: Recording user engagement, ms: 1211
D: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=1211, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=SelectActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-8244797341152687840}]
E: (1032) statement aborts at 13: [INSERT INTO crash_reports(size,payload,ts,fatal) VALUES (?,?,?,?)] attempt to write a readonly database
E: Error inserting size=10565 payload=[B@1f409e5 ts=1526448971731 fatal=1
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException: attempt to write a readonly database (code 1032)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:783)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1548)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1417)
        at bbx.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@12673025@12.6.73 (040408-194189626):45)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Answer (score -1):

To write to a SqlDatabase you need to get a writeable instance, using `getWritableDatabase()`. If this doesn't solve it we need to see your code snippets to get better insight

Comment: Actually i dont have any database in my app. I thought the firebase try to write in own database inside of my app. So that it happened. More over i cannot do like you said